# Permanent States in React - React-Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, navbar

I have a problem: I have a NavBar that loads an AJAX which retrieves a name and another data. Well, the problem is that this data stores them in states of the declared component itself as NavBar.jsx and when I use routes (react-router) the component is mounted and dismantled losing its states, therefore, every time that change of route has That re-make the AJAX call. This same problem I have for a button 'Enter', which has status 1 and when someone is logged in takes 0 status, but every time I change the route returns to state 1 (as if it were not logged, although it is actually logged). My question is: How can I create states that are maintained despite changing routes? (I know this is not possible, with states I am referring to variables, or anything I can declare that does not change value every time you reassemble the components, in this case NavBar, when changing paths. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved in several ways.

1. save the returned data in localStorage, check in localStorage before doing the ajax call, is the data exists, just use it instead.
2. Use redux - this moves the state to the app level instead of the component, unmounting the component will not delete the state.
3. do not re-render the navbar on each navigation(if it's possible in your app).
   See the tutorial for nested routes for react-router ; 
   https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/04-nested-routes

this option means that route changes will only re-render the "internal page" and not constant things like the navbar, submenu, footer etc.

Comment: The first option is the 'most incorrect' truth. The second option ... In this project I do not have to use Redux. The third option would be the best, knowing that I do not have to use Redux, right?

Comment: I tend to agree, if you don't have to use redux, don't use redux. if option 3 solves your problem I think it's the cleanest approach